# How to match street name and numbers from faulty string

Tags: ruby, regex

How to change this regex so this will match street names bellow

Most of string are faulty like that:

> "Street name 12a tallinn 11617 harjumaa" = > Group one:"Street name" => Group two:"12a"
> "11617 harjumaa, Street name 12a, tallinn"

**I need format like that:**

> "Street name 12a" => group one: "Street name", Group two "12a"
>
> "Streetname/1", "Streetname-1", "Abaja - Merja tee" => Group one

And other complex addresses should work
"Street name 7/2-508a"

Here my regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/cYCafR/9

```
(\d{1,2}\.[\wöäüõ. \/-]+|[\wöäüõ. \/-]+|[A-z. -]+)\s(?:(\d+(?:[A-Za-z]+)?(\/|\-))(\d+(?:[A-Za-z]+)?(?:\/|\-)?(?:\d+(?:[A-Za-z]+)?)?))
```

Comment: Try `your_string[/(\p{L}+(?:\s*(?:-\s*)?\p{L}+)*)(?:[\s\/-](\d+\p{L}*(?:[-\/]\d+\p{L}*)*))?/]`. I think it works as expected on almost all your inputs, but I am not sure as for `M. Härma tn 4-7/39`.

Comment: What about when the number is in front of the street's name (link in Australia e.q. _300 King Street_)? What if the name of the street includes a number too (like _Straße des 17. Juni 135_)?

Comment: Just thinking about [falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Comment: @spickermann I have recalled exactly the same.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/CiQqd9

Comment: Does my suggestion help in any way? I will remove the comments if they are not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please DON'T! :D It was helpful. I can't use as you did but you gave me idea.

Comment: Shall I post with explanations? Actually, I could help much better if you explained the "rules", the requirements. Just trying to match arbitrary strings is not helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: `(?|(.*?[ ]+(\d+(?:\/[\d-]+)?[a-zA-Z]*)).*|(.*))`

https://regex101.com/r/Nqpjom/1/

Comment: How to find address when sometimes string is faulty like that "Street name 12a tallinn 11617 harjumaa" ?

Comment: Then we should differentiate between "complex" addresses and "faulty" ones. Could you provide the rules for complex addresses?

Comment: Complex ones already matching, like "Akadeemia tee 7/2-508a" and grouping like I need them.